# Changing android:layout_weight makes OnTouchListener not working

Tags: android, android-layout, android-view, android-layout-weight

I am trying to implement a virtual joystick that is sending data through a socket. I want data to be sent only when user is pressing (touching) the joystick. Everything was working fine with the code, but I decided that joystick view should be bigger. To achieve it i changed the `android:layout_weight` in the `leftSide` RelativeLayout from 4 to 3. After this adjustment on touch events are never registered. Joystick animation is working perfectly though. Reverting changes make the program work again.

What is happening here? What are the other ways to make view bigger on the screen?

I have the following layout file

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:baselineAligned="false"
    tools:context="com.my.package.DisplayControlActivity">

<RelativeLayout 
    android:id="@+id/leftSide"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="3" >
    <!-- working fine with android:layout_weight="4" -->

    <SurfaceView
        android:id="@+id/videoStream"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
    </SurfaceView>
</RelativeLayout>  

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/rightSide"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/testImage"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:contentDescription="@string/test_image"
        android:scaleType="fitStart"
        android:src="@drawable/test_image" >
    </ImageView>

    <com.my.package.SquareJoystickView
            android:id="@+id/virtual_joystick"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">
    </com.my.package.SquareJoystickView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

And here is OnTouchListerer part of the code:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    /* some irrelevant code */
    joystickView = (SquareJoystickView) findViewById(R.id.virtual_joystick);                
    isSending = false;      
    joystickView.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {               
                isSending = false;
              }
            if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                isSending = true;
              }
            return true;
        }
    });             
}
```

Comment: I guess there are certain variables that are used in SquareJoystickView.java to change the layout of the joystick. So try to change the layout programmaticly instead of xml

Comment: Also, LinearLayout isn't closed. I'm very interested in the result, because I'm working on the exact same thing.

Comment: LinearLayout is closed. It seems i didn't copy the last line.

Comment: @moffeltje. Yes, SquareJoystickView is changed programmatically - it takes the value which is set to "match_parent" (width or height) and adjust the second to ensure that joystick is a square.

I've also found out that this issue happens only when testImage and virtual_joystick overlap. I think I'll try to set up layout programmatically.